# How can I create a shell alias for creating a new script and opening it in the editor?

Tags: bash, shell, alias

Shell script shortcuts or aliases are very useful for automating repetitive tasks in very few key strokes.

One example of example of "shortcut" command is `take` from `zsh` which does `mkdir $dir && cd $dir`.

I want to make something similar (`medit`) that does this: when called `medit script.sh`:

- creates script
- makes it executable (chmod +x)
- populates it with shebang line
- opens the file in the default editor

Can I do this using an alias so I would avoid writing a bash script that does that?

Answer (score 2):

You better write a function like:

```
function medit(){
    echo "#!/bin/bash" > "$1"
    chmod +x "$1"
    if [ -n "$VISUAL" ]; then
        "$VISUAL" "$1"
    elif [ -n "$EDITOR" ]; then
        "$EDITOR" "$1"
    else
        vi "$1"
    fi
}
```

Put it to .bashrc and call it with `medit script.sh`
It will first try to run the editor specified in `$VISUAL` and `$EDITOR` and falls back to `vi` if there is no standard editor specified.

Comment: I would `test -f` the file before creating a new one.

Answer (score 2):

I would write something like this:

```
# Usage: just like 'builtin printf'
fatal_error() {
  builtin printf "$@" >&2
  exit 1
}

# Usage: medit [file] [more arguments]
medit() {
  # If we have arguments
  if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    # If $1 file does not exist, or is empty,
    # put a shebang line into it. See `help test`.
    if [ ! -s "$1" ]; then
      printf "%s\n" "#!/bin/bash -" > "$1" || \
        fatal_error "Failed to write to %s\n" "$1"
    fi

    # Make $1 executable
    chmod +x "$1" || fatal_error "failed to chmod %s\n" "$1"
  fi

  # Run the default editor with the arguments passed to this function
  "${EDITOR:-${VISUAL:-vi}}" "$@"
}
```

The `medit` command can be invoked just like the default editor, even without arguments.

---

On the off-chance that you don't know how to re-use the script above, put the code into some `~/scripts/medit`, and `source` it from the appropriate initialization script such as `~/.bashrc`: `source ~/scripts/medit`.

Comment: Quite an wonderful implementation. I do see one bug: it should create the file only if it doesn't exist as we don't want accidents. The other remarks is only a personal preference of not defining a new utility function only to save two lines of code but that one is just a preference.

Comment: @sorin, added a `[ ! -s "$1" ]` test

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is an alias.
There is no way to do all you ask without using one or several functions.
But there is a way to make an alias define some functions and also call them:

```
alias medit='
SayError(){ local a=$1; shift; printf "%s\n" "$0: $@" >&2; exit "$a"; }
medit(){
    [[ $# -lt 1 ]] && 
        SayError 1 "We need at least the name of the file as an argument"
    [[ ! -s $1 ]] && echo "#!/bin/bash" > "$1" ||
        SayError 2 "File $1 already exists"
    chmod u+x "$1" || 
        SayError 3 "File $1 could not be made executable"
    ${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-emacs}} "$1" ||
        SayError 4 "File $1 could not be open in the editor"
}
\medit'
```

You need to execute the above definition of the alias `medit` or place it in `~/.bashrc`, or simply source it in the running shell to make it exist.

Then, when the alias is called, it defines two functions: `SayError` and `medit`.
Yes, a function with the same name as the alias: `medit`.

After the function definition, the alias will call the function by using a trick:

```
\medit
```

As (strictly speaking) a `\medit` is not exactly the alias `medit`, bash keeps searching and finds the function `medit`, which by then has been defined and is executed.

Of course, you can just define the functions and use them without resorting to an alias to make the definition of the functions, that's your choice.

What is nice is to have the choice. :)

This is how you could define all in a sourced file:

```
alias medit='\medit'
SayError(){ local a=$1; shift; printf "%s\n" "$0: $@" >&2; exit "$a"; }
medit(){
    [[ $# -lt 1 ]] && 
        SayError 1 "We need at least the name of the file as an argument"
    [[ ! -s $1 ]] && echo "#!/bin/bash" > "$1" ||  
        SayError 2 "File $1 already exists"
    chmod u+x "$1" || 
        SayError 3 "File $1 could not be made executable"
    ${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-emacs}} "$1" || 
        SayError 4 "File $1 could not be open in the editor"
}
```